# Send multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Is there a way to do the following solution in Internet Explorer? (IE7 and up)

link: [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

The solution code works great in every browser but IE.

Comment: use this for multipart/format data  http://www.freshdesignweb.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2011/01/ajax-file-upload.zip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't use `jQuery.ajax` to upload files and `FormData` isn't supported by IE unfortunately.

Check out the [Uploadify jQuery plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/) to upload files via ajax. You can also use [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to upload files via ajax.

Comment: Does this support file upload?

Comment: Update, as of today, Uploadify claims it is not compatible with IE < 10. Anyway, +1 for suggesting JQuery Form Plugin

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, IE doesn't support the `FormData` API yet.  However, you can achieve something similar using any number of jQuery AJAX form post plugins, such as [this one](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started).

Answer (score -1):

I too have faced this problem ,it may be useful to some one in need .
**FormData** is supported only  from IE10 onwards here's [a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772723(v=vs.85).aspx).Error because you cannot bind input fields in old browsers, like in a modern ones using FormData. 
 You cannot upload files through AJAX in IE.Their are two alternative ways to do

- Use some plugin like Uploadify jQuery plugin to upload files via
  ajax. You can also use jQuery Form Plugin to
  [multi](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Examples)
  and [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
- Other way is you may use iframe.

Here's is the code

```
  if(!isAjaxUploadSupported()){ //IE fallfack
            var iframe = document.createElement("<iframe name='upload_iframe_myFile' id='upload_iframe_myFile'>");
            iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("src","javascript:false;");
            iframe.style.display = "none";

            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe_myFile");
            form.setAttribute("action", "fileupload.aspx"); //change page to post
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
            form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
            form.style.display = "block";

            var files = document.getElementById("myFile");//Upload Id
            form.appendChild(files);
            $conv("#container_myFile").html("Uploading...");

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframeIdmyFile = document.getElementById("upload_iframe_myFile");

            // Add event...
            var eventHandlermyFile = function () {
                if (iframeIdmyFile.detachEvent) 
                    iframeIdmyFile.detachEvent("onload", eventHandlermyFile);
                else 
                    iframeIdmyFile.removeEventListener("load", eventHandlermyFile, false);

                response = getIframeContentJSON(iframeIdmyFile);

            }

            if (iframeIdmyFile.addEventListener) 
                iframeIdmyFile.addEventListener("load", eventHandlermyFile, true);
            if (iframeIdmyFile.attachEvent) 
                iframeIdmyFile.attachEvent("onload", eventHandlermyFile);

            form.submit();

            return;
        }
        ////var data = new FormData();
        //// code go here(for modern browsers)


        function isAjaxUploadSupported(){
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "file";

                return (
                    "multiple" in input &&
                        typeof File != "undefined" &&
                        typeof FormData != "undefined" &&
                        typeof (new XMLHttpRequest()).upload != "undefined" );
        }
        function getIframeContentJSON(iframe){
                //IE may throw an "access is denied" error when attempting to access contentDocument on the iframe in some cases
                try {
                    // iframe.contentWindow.document - for IE<7
                    var doc = iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument: iframe.contentWindow.document,
                        response;

                    var innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
                    //plain text response may be wrapped in <pre> tag
                    if (innerHTML.slice(0, 5).toLowerCase() == "<pre>" && innerHTML.slice(-6).toLowerCase() == "</pre>") {
                        innerHTML = doc.body.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
                    }
                    response = eval("(" + innerHTML + ")");
                } catch(err){
                    response = {success: false};
                }

                return response;
            }
```

Comment: innerHTML and eval extremely likely to cause XSS security flaws.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772723(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -2):

Try to set forms' attributes like this:

> $( "#yourformid" ) .attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" ) .attr(
>   "encoding", "multipart/form-data" );

or rather try to find ready-made jquery upload plugin

Comment: `FormData` isn't supported by IE < 10. Only for IE10+