# 'FormData' is undefined in IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, form-data

I have a problem where i need to post the data as content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
    var inputData = {cId:"444",pageNo:"1",latitude:"49.153236",longitude:"12.040905"};
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('data', JSON.stringify(inputData));


    this.model.save(data, {
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (model, resultData) {
            $.get(App.baseUrl + 'templates/all-offers-view.html', function (data) {
                template = _.template(data, {
                    data: resultData
                });
                that.$el.html(template);
            }, 'html');

        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

While the above works fine in all other browsers, I am getting the following error in IE9.

```
SCRIPT5009: 'FormData' is undefined 
view.js, line 57 character 9
```

line 57 being `var data = new FormData();`

Ive heard `FormData()` is a browser dependant function and its not related to jquery library and that in IE its missing.

The reason why i am using the above method is because i have to pass data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

I cannot change the server side coding(as this is linked with an iphone app in appstore).

All i can do is try out with the client-side.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

p.s : I am using backbone.js.

Comment: The [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility) at MDN indicates you might have issues with more than IE. There is also a [link for how to submit the form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest) without the formData API.

Comment: :(.. that is very bad... ill try out the fix...

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
if(typeof FormData == "undefined"){
var data = [];
data.push('data', JSON.stringify(inputData));
}
else{
var data = new FormData();
    data.append('data', JSON.stringify(inputData));
}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Lines 2 and 3 don't solve the problem with IE 8.  I'm hoping this post will http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475215/formdata-in-ie8-9