# FormData is undefined error in IE 11

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to use upload control in angular Js. The functionality works fine in chrome, but does not work in IE 11.
Below is the code used:

```
      <div>
 <input type="file" class="form-control" id="imageUploadfile" name="Imagefile" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" accept="image/*" />
<input type="button" name="imageUploadButton" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />
</div>
```

In the controller.js file,

```
  var formdata;
$scope.getTheFiles = function ($files) {
    formdata = new FormData();
    angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
        formdata.append(key, value);
    });
};


$scope.uploadFiles = function () {
    TestAPIService.postUploadImage(formdata).success(function (response) {
        var imageurl = _TestBaseUrl + 'Images/' + response.filePath.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
        $scope.testTypeImage_url = imageurl;
    }).error(function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    });
};
```

The above code is working fine in chrome, where I am able to upload the file. The error is in formdata , as the "key, value" are not getting added.

How to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: add this : `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to your meta tag and check.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486597/formdata-is-undefined-in-ie-only

Comment: why u re using angular loop to get the key of the file. Try var formData = new FormData(); formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above code did not work. formdata is still coming as undefined

Comment: Any solution to this? Is there any other option which can be used for IE 11. The above code works in chrome. I want to have this functionality in IE 11

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me,

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

using 'IE=edge' it will instruct to IE to use the latest document mode available. It is recommended to have this meta tag in your webpages which specially involved with JQuery/Ajax implementations.

Answer (score 2):

FormData is not fully supported by IE11 so you might need to polyfill it. Only the `constructor` and the `append` method are supported by IE, [all other methods are unsupported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

You can find a polyfill here: https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData