# FormData in IE 11 not defined

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, form-data

I have the following script to get the file data from a input type of file:

```
var uploadfiles = $("#upFile").get(0);
var uploadedfiles = uploadfiles.files;

var fromdata = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < uploadedfiles.length; i++) {
    fromdata.append(uploadedfiles[i].name, uploadedfiles[i]);
}

// ajax code omitted that uploads file
```

This works great in all browsers I have tested with, except IE 11.  In this it doesn't understand what FormData() is?? I have read quite a few different workarounds online now but NONE of them work, whatever I try nothing is able to get the details of the file from the input.  Has anyone else had this that can help?  Even if I try using jQuery to get the object then the 'files' is undefined for some reason.

EDIT: Reading more online, it seems it could be because IE doesn't give access to the input until the form has been submitted, however I am using ajax to upload the file so I can't really submit it.

EDIT2: I should also mention that this code is called on the change event of the file input, not sure if it has any relevance but best to mention it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After checking docmode in IE developer tools it turned out it was reverted to 9 for some reason, had an older meta tag for X-UA-Compatible on my master page which I changed to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

And FormData had no problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

FormData is not fully supported on IE11.

To be specific: FormData instance does not have method 'set'.
You need to use append method instead, as follows:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('your_key_name', 'your_value_goes_here');
```

Setting meta http-equiv to IE=edge will not make 'set' property work and is not needed.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append