# File upload using Ajax and ashx not working in IE

Tags: c#, ajax, internet-explorer, file-upload, ashx

I'm uploading a file using ajax and ashx file and it works well in other browser except in Internet Explorer (IE11), I had also search the web and tried different suggestions but still failed.

Here is my ajax code:

```
function uploadFile() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('#fileupload')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'fileUploader.ashx',
            data: formData,
            success: alert("Success!"),
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            error: function () {
                alert("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
}
```

Here is my ashx code:

```
public class fileUploader : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        try
        {
            string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Attachment_/");
            string[] files;
            files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
            string str_file = "";

            foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                {
                    //save to path
                    fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    str_file = "Attachment_" +fileName;
                    string pathToSave = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Attachment_/") + str_file;
                    file.SaveAs(pathToSave);
                }
            }


            context.Response.Write(str_file);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong? I tried and tested this on other browser specially chrome and the above codes are working, but it fails on IE. It also doesn't throw any error, and shows the `alert("Success")` message, but the file is not being uploaded. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: FormData is not defined 
please refer to this - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206105/formdata-in-ie-11-not-defined

Comment: I had already seen it and it also doesn't work for me :( I tried this <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" /> and <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> but still fails in IE.

Comment: Use AjaxForm not FormData

Comment: Hi @viveknuna do you have samples? sorry I'm new with ajaxForm. How will I convert? Thanks!

Comment: I am uploading files with [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html) and processing (in my case: saving) them with a generic handler. Works pretty fine for me. Have you considered using this jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
string fileName = file.FileName;
```

use

```
Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
```