# PHP AJAX Image Uploading with FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am relatively new to jQuery and Ajax functions, but have been working with Ajax forms over the past few days. I have come to a problem with file uploads however when trying to upload images. Whilst looking for resources, I couldn't find anything useful because they seem to be over-complicated with pointless extras or have no explanation whatsoever, which doesn't help me to learn any further.

I have wrote this code to handle the image upload in Ajax:

```
$(function() {
    $('.input_photo').on("change",function() {                              
        var formData = new FormData($('form.upload-form'));

        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This sends a request to the `upload.php` file, however no data is sent, basically my form is literally this:

```
<form class="upload-form">
     <input type="file" name="input_photo" class="input_photo" />
</form>
```

No data seems to be passed in the headers whatsoever and I assume I would access it through PHP with `$_POST['data']` array or `$_FILES`? Someone with better knowledge please help to explain this, it'd be great to understand this further.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work for one or multiple files.

```
$('input:file').on('change', function () {  

 var data = new FormData();

 //Append files infos
 jQuery.each($(this)[0].files, function(i, file) {
     data.append('file-'+i, file);
 });

 $.ajax({  
     url: "my_path",  
     type: "POST",  
     data: data,  
     cache: false,
     processData: false,  
     contentType: false, 
     context: this,
     success: function (msg) {
          alert(msg);
      }
  });
});
```

Then

```
$_FILES['file-0']
$_FILES['file-1']
[...]
```

But be careful that [using `FormData` doesn't work on IE before IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475215/formdata-in-ie8-9)

Comment: Worked perfectly first time, although I changed it to **.on('change')** since live is deprecated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `processData` and  `contentType` in your ajax call ( also added id to your `input` element in order to fetch the file contents).

HTML

```
    <form class="upload-form">
         <input type="file" id="photo" name="input_photo" class="input_photo" /> 
    </form>
```

JS

```
  $(function() {
        $('.input_photo').on("change",function() {    
            var file = document.getElementById("photo").files[0]; //fetch file
            var formData = new FormData();                     
            formData.append('file', file); //append file to formData object

            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false, //prevent jQuery from converting your FormData into a string
                contentType: false, //jQuery does not add a Content-Type header for you
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg)
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just tried pretty much this exact code from another question and it just passes an empty $_FILES array for some reason.

Answer (score -2):

Try with this:

```
var formData = $('form.upload-form').serialize();
```

Comment: That only posts form data, not file data.