# PHP form submit and status information popup without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating simple CMS for uploading AR Vuforia Markers for my mobile app. I have working php form that is:

1. Uploading one image (target) to server
2. That target sending to Vuforia Cloud
3. Uploading data from form to database
4. Uploading other files to server

So everything is working correctly, but now I am trying to display popup after clicking submit with status informations.

Simple popup with text:

1. Uploading target to server
2. Sending target to Vuforia Cloud
3. Uploading data from form to database
4. Uploading other files to server

after every step is completed text is just colouring in green (in error case on red) and at the end unlocking OK button.
I trying different solutions from here with progress bar i.e. [Display progress bar while the php script is running through ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261363/display-progress-bar-while-the-php-script-is-running-through-ajax) in spite of various attempts, I am still doing something wrong. I know that jquery is not my strong side.

form file (insert_gallery.php) is:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/css/all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .progress {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            width: 0;
            height: 3px;
            background: red;
            transition: width .3s;
        }
        .progress.hide {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 1.3s;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="config_main_window">
            <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="vuforia/upload_gallery.php" id="upload_target">
                <div class="title">TARGET</div>
                <div class = "row" id="markerRow" >
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="markerfile" class="media-desc"><span style="color: red">* </span>target (.jpg)</label>
                        <input name="markerfile" id="markerfile" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;" required>
                        <canvas id="markerCanvas" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px"></canvas>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block; float: right">
                        <label for="category" class="media-desc"><span style="color: red">* </span>category:</label>
                        <select id="category" name="category" size="1" class="custom-select">
                            <option value="education">Education</option>
                            <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                            <option value="shopping"> Shopping </option>
                            <option value="contests"> Contests </option>
                            <option value="games"> Games </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 50px; float: right">
                        <label for="for_adults" class="media-desc"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="for_adults" name="for_adults" style="margin-right: 5px">+18</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 50px; float: right">
                        <label for="is_active" class="media-desc"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="is_active" name="is_active" style="margin-right: 5px">active</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class = "row" style="height: 40px">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="target_name" id="target_name" type="text" class="form-control-input" placeholder="Title..." required>
                        <input name="target_client" id="target_client" type="text" class="form-control-input" style="margin-left: 6px;" placeholder="Client..." required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class = "row" style="padding-bottom: 25px">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="target_desc" id="target_desc" class="form-control-textarea" style="resize: none;" placeholder="Opis..." required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class = "row" style="height: 30px">
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile1" class="media-desc"><span style="color: red">* </span>photo 1 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile1" id="mediafile1" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile2" class="media-desc"> photo 2 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile2" id="mediafile2" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class = "row" style="margin-left: 9px; height: 30px">
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile3" class="media-desc"> photo 3 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile3" id="mediafile3" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                        <canvas id="markerCanvas" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile4" class="media-desc"> photo 4 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile4" id="mediafile4" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class = "row" style="margin-left: 9px; height: 30px">
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile5" class="media-desc"> photo 5 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile5" id="mediafile5" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile6" class="media-desc"> photo 6 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile6" id="mediafile6" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class = "row" style="margin-left: 9px; height: 30px">
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile7" class="media-desc"> photo 7 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile7" id="mediafile7" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile8" class="media-desc"> photo 8 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile8" id="mediafile8" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class = "row" style="margin-left: 9px; height: 30px">
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile9" class="media-desc"> photo 9 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile9" id="mediafile9" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="mediafile10" class="media-desc"> photo 10 (.jpg or .png)</label>
                        <input name="mediafile10" id="mediafile10" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="title">NEWSFEED</div>

                <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 50px;">
                    <label for="newsfeed" class="media-desc"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="newsfeed" name="newsfeed" style="margin-right: 5px">show in newsfeed</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 50px;">
                    <label for="time_campaign" class="media-desc"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="time_campaign" name="time_campaign" style="margin-right: 5px">time campaign</label>
                </div>

                <div class = "row" style="margin-left: 9px; height: 30px; padding-top:20px">
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="main_photo" class="media-desc">photo (newsfeed) (.jpg lub .png)</label>
                        <input name="main_photo" id="main_photo" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; float: left">
                        <label for="main_video" class="media-desc">video (newsfeed) (.mp4)</label>
                        <input name="main_video" id="main_video" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="targetAdded()" style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="short_desc" id="short_desc" class="form-control-textarea" style="resize: none;" maxlength="80" placeholder="Short description..." required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "row" style="padding-bottom: 25px">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="long_desc" class="form-control-textarea" style="resize: none;" placeholder="Long description..." required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    <script>
     
      $(function() {
        // Set onclick
        let markerfile = $('#markerfile');
        let category = $('#category');
        let for_adults = $('#for_adults');
        let is_active = $('#is_active');
        let target_name = $('#target_name');
        let target_client = $('#target_client');
        let target_desc = $('#target_desc');
        let mediafile1 = $('#mediafile1');
        let mediafile2 = $('#mediafile2');
        let mediafile3 = $('#mediafile3');
        let mediafile4 = $('#mediafile4');
        let mediafile5 = $('#mediafile5');
        let mediafile6 = $('#mediafile6');
        let mediafile7 = $('#mediafile7');
        let mediafile8 = $('#mediafile8');
        let mediafile9 = $('#mediafile9');
        let mediafile10 = $('#mediafile10');
        let newsfeed = $('#newsfeed');
        let time_campaign = $('#time_campaign');
        let main_photo = $('#main_photo');
        let main_video = $('#main_video');
        let short_desc = $('#short_desc');
        let long_desc = $('#long_desc');

        let dataString = 'markerfile='+ markerfile + '&category=' + category + '&for_adults=' + for_adults + '&is_active=' + is_active + '&target_name=' + target_name + '&target_client=' + target_client + '&target_desc=' + target_desc + '&newsfeed=' + newsfeed + '&time_campaign=' + time_campaign + '&short_desc=' + short_desc + '&long_desc=' + long_desc;


        $('#submit').click(function(){
            // Ajax call
            $.ajax({
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                console.log(percentComplete);
                                $('.progress').css({
                                    width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                                });
                                if (percentComplete === 1) {
                                    $('.progress').addClass('hide');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, false);

                    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                            console.log(percentComplete);
                            $('.progress').css({
                                width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                            });
                        }
                    }, false);

                    return xhr;
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/admin/vuforia/upload_gallery.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function (data) {
                    
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and upload_gallery.php:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    require '../../misc/db_connection.php';
    require '../../misc/ftp_connection.php';
    include 'vuforiaclient.php';

    if(isset($_POST['for_adults'])){$for_adults = 1;} else {$for_adults = 0;}
    if(isset($_POST['is_active'])){$is_active = 1;} else {$is_active = 0;}
    if(isset($_POST['newsfeed'])){$newsfeed = 1;} else {$newsfeed = 0;}
    if(isset($_POST['time_campaign'])){$time_campaign = 1;} else {$time_campaign = 0;}


    $db = getConnection();
    $next_id = "SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'vuforia' AND TABLE_NAME = 'targets'";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($next_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $target_next_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    $target_category = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['category']));
    $target_type = 'gallery';

    $markerfile = $_FILES['markerfile']['name'];
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($markerfile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $uploadOk = 1;

  
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
        echo "To big file.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if($imageFileType != "jpg") {
        echo "Only JPG";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

    if (!ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass)) {
        exit('FTP Login Failed');
    }

    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

    if ($uploadOk == 1) {
        $renamedFile = $target_next_id."_".$target_category."_".$target_type;
        $remote_marker_path = "/storage_gallery/targets/".$renamedFile;
        $marker_upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_marker_path.'.jpg', $_FILES["markerfile"]["tmp_name"], FTP_BINARY);
    }

    ftp_close($conn_id);

    if($marker_upload){

        $imagePath = 'https://....../storage_gallery/targets/';
        $imageName = $renamedFile.'.jpg';

        $client = new VuforiaClient();

        // add a target to vuforia.
        $vuforiaTargetID = $client->addTarget($imagePath,$imageName,$target_category,$target_next_id,$target_type);

        if ($vuforiaTargetID){
            $data = [
                'target_type' => 'gallery',
                'target_id' => trim(htmlspecialchars($vuforiaTargetID)),
                'target_category' => trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['category'])),
                'target_status' => 'Processing',
                'target_image' => 'https://....../storage_gallery/targets/'.$renamedFile.'.jpg',
                'for_adults' => trim(htmlspecialchars($for_adults)),
                'is_active' => trim(htmlspecialchars($is_active)),
                'target_name' => trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['target_name'])),
                'target_client' => trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['target_client'])),
                'target_desc' => trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['target_desc'])),
                'newsfeed' => trim(htmlspecialchars($newsfeed)),
                'time_campaign' => trim(htmlspecialchars($time_campaign)),
                'short_desc' => trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['short_desc'])),
                'long_desc' => trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['long_desc'])),
                'is_deleted' => '0',

            ];

            $insert_marker = "INSERT INTO `targets`
                                     (`created_at`, `target_type`, `target_id`, `target_category`, `target_status`, `target_image`, `for_adult`, `is_active`, `target_name`, `target_client`, `target_desc`, `newsfeed`, `time_campaign`, `short_desc`, `long_desc`, `is_deleted`)
                                VALUES
                                     (NOW(), :target_type, :target_id, :target_category, :target_status, :target_image,  :for_adults, :is_active, :target_name, :target_client, :target_desc, :newsfeed, :time_campaign, :short_desc, :long_desc, :is_deleted)";

             $db = getConnection();
             $stmt = $db->prepare($insert_marker);
             $run_gallery = $stmt->execute($data);
        }
    }

    if($run_gallery){
        echo "<script>alert('Target added')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('../?'.$target_category,'_self')</script>";
    }

}
```

Comment: to do it you should split the activities in multiple steps. Each step should be executed in the callback of the previous one ensuring that the first is completed before starting the second and so on. On entering the next callback you can update your progress bar

Comment: most of it looks OK except:
percentComplete * 100 + '%' perhaps put computation in brackets like "" + (percentComplete * 100) + '%' and 
(percentComplete === 1)  should be something like Math.abs( percentComplete ) == 1 with a double equal sign