# How to upload file using pure vanilla javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, form-data

I have an existing html form which uploads a file to the server as soon as the user selects an image file.

I have done something like this.

```
//html code
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" accept="image/*" />
// the usual html stuff

document.getElementById('photo').addEventListener("change",uploadImage);
function uploadImage()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST","/upload.php",true);    
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","image");

    var file = document.getElementById('photo').files[0];
    if(file)
    {
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("pic",file);
        xhr.send(formdata);
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
             //some code
    }
};
}
```

But in my php file, I can't access this uploaded file. The `$_POST` array seems to be empty. I did a `print_r` for `$_POST` and it gave `Array()`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do know that file uploads are in `$_FILES`, and not `$_POST`, corrrect?

Comment: Yes that is empty too...

Comment: You shouldn't need to set content-type as XHR should automatically detect that you have appended a file and use `multipart/form-data`. And php does not understand content-type `image` either which is why you are not getting anything

Comment: Such a careless mistake on my part. You are right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using `FormData` which works very much the same way a normal form does.

First of all, in PHP files will not be in `$_POST` but instead in `$_FILES`, [see the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

What that documentation does mention, along with the `$_FILES` buffer, is that you need to use the `multipart/form-data` encoding, any `FormData` transferred through an `XMLHttpRequest` will have this set by default, though you may want to check it if the `$_FILES` remain empty.
You should remove the `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","image");` and let the `XHR` object handle it, of - if that doesn't work - add

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
```

There is a pretty nice example [right here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644773/php-ajax-image-uploading-with-formdata)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I removed it and now I have something in my `$_FILES` .