# Upload files in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetFiles(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {            
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);   
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return Json("Uploaded " + Request.Files.Count + " files",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now I want to upload files in Ajax and save files another folder.
How to get files from input form and send it via Ajax?

Comment: You have not shown your ajax call. You need to use `FormData` is posting files using ajax. Refer [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: I'm try it don't work. If you know working version please tell me

Comment: Tried what? You have not shown your code so how can we guess what you have done wrong

Comment: I'm trying multiple forms of FormData searching in internet. but my FormData aslo stayed empty, and I can't get it in my controller!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

cshtml:

```
<input id="myFile" type="file" name="myfile" onchange="GoToPreview(this)" style="display: none">



function GoToPreview(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {  

                var tmpImageData = new FileReader();
                tmpImageData.onload = function (e) {
                    SetImageData(imageData);                
                }
                tmpImageData.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
    }

function SetImageData(imageData) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/SetImageData',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { imageData: imageData },
            success: function (data) {
                // code here
            },
            error: function (data) {
                // code for exception
            }
        });
    }
```

In SetImageData method at server side do your thing.

Answer (score 0):

As @Reza Aghaei already said you can use `FormData` to solve your problem, but i recommend you `ajaxForm()` method from [this library](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). I use this approach becouse [IE8 and IE9 do not support `FormData`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15498972/1849444)

And it really is not difficult to use it.