# upload files without form submit

Tags: php, ajax, forms, iframe, file-upload

I have a form that contains both data inputs and file inputs. Now i want to upload files selected right after selection without submitting the form, because form submit will send other data. The reason that i want upload files before submitting form is saving the time, so when the user is filling the form, files will be uploaded.

As i understood i need to use iframes, because ajax can not simply send files, and formData is not supported in IE. But i couldn't find a clear example of it.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Look at [FormData in ie8 ie9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475215/formdata-in-ie8-9) I think it is good example.

Comment: you can upload files with ajax http://stackoverflow.com/a/4943774/4233593