# Post ajaxForm from Struts 2 file upload utility not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, struts2, ajaxform

**Background:**
I am looking for a tool to upload big file asynchronously using Ajax + Struts 2, I was able to do the same thing using servlet but when I modify the logic to call Struts action. I have noticed that when I try to upload a huge file using Struts 2 action, it doesn't get called from jQuery `ajaxForm(options);`

I have used the sample code specified on the below link this works perfectly fine.
http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery-in-servlet/

Can anyone tell if below jQuery function call is correct for upload functionality.

```
$("#uploadtest").ajaxForm(options);
```

I tried but it is not working as expected in one particular browser when huge data is uploaded.
(That is, client ajax call occurs, however, the corresponding Struts 2 action is not getting called in the backend, logs are not generated on the server side).

I am not able to understand why Struts 2 action is not getting called when jQuery `ajaxform` to upload huge file (multipart upload functionality).

**jQuery:**

```
$("#uploadtest").ajaxForm(options);
```

**JSP snippet:**

```
<s:form id="uploadtest" name="uploadform" action="aStrutsAction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15475215/5086633).

Comment: How it is not working? Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: `I tried but it is not working as expected` you should clarify this.

Comment: @RomanC thanks. updated the question.

Comment: @yeppe if struts2 action is working then it' a browser compatibility issue for the javascript code used with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with uploading big files to the Struts2 action is that request may not comply the limits used by default with Struts2. In configuration settings the value is set to 2097152. You can also set the limits per action. More about it you can find in [Struts2 File Upload - Advanced Configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload.html#advanced-configuration):

> The Struts 2 `default.properties` file defines several settings that affect the behavior of file uploading. You may find in necessary to change these values. The names and default values are:
>
> ```
> struts.multipart.parser=jakarta
> struts.multipart.saveDir=
> struts.multipart.maxSize=2097152
> ```

---

The next section from this docs page is [File Size Limits](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload.html#file-size-limits) where you have noticed about limitations of the file size used by the underline frameworks (struts2, commons-fileupload):

> There are two separate file size limits. First is
> `struts.multipart.maxSize` which comes from the Struts 2
> `default.properties` file. This setting exists for security reasons to
> prohibit a malicious user from uploading extremely large files to file
> up your servers disk space. This setting defaults to approximately 2
> megabytes and should be adjusted to the maximum size file (**2 gigs max**)
> that your will need the framework to receive. If you are uploading
> more than one file on a form the `struts.multipart.maxSize` applies to
> the combined total, not the individual file sizes. The other setting,
> `maximumSize`, is an interceptor setting that is used to ensure a
> particular Action does not receive a file that is too large. Notice
> the locations of both settings in the following example:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
>     "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" 
>     "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
> <struts>
>     <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />
>      
>     <action name="doUpload" class="com.example.UploadAction">
>         <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
>         <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
>             <param name="maximumSize">500000</param>
>         </interceptor-ref> 
>         <interceptor-ref name="validation"/>
>         <interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>
>  
>         <result name="success">good_result.jsp</result>
>     </action>
> </struts>
> ```

---

If the file size exceeds the above configuration settings, the pseudo progress bar stops as soon as it returns a response. It could be 1% or 100% it depends on thresh speed and a file size. But on the server side you might see an exception

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (xxx) exceeds the configured maximum (yyy)
```

and the following warnings. You might adjust the file size limitations with the framework if it doesn't exceed the framework's limitations itself.