# Creating multipart/mixed request with JSON data and file in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, multipart-mixed-replace

Can we build request similar to below in IE 9 browser, which doesn't have formData support.

```
POST /someUrl
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=xyz

--xyz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="meta-data"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{
   "name": "value"
}
--xyz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-data"; filename="file.properties"
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
... File Data ...
```

Comment: Not technically a duplicate, but it may still answer your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475215/formdata-in-ie8-9

Comment: I have gone through that post before putting this question, as they are posting data as same as old style through iframe for oid browser. I agree we could only use that way for file upload in SPA.

Is that mean, there is no way to build custom request data for IE9 browsers?

Comment: Not really. IE is archaic at the best of times