# e.preventDefault not working in IE when using new formData (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, multipartform-data, preventdefault

These seems to be a fairly common issue so I've stripped it down to the bare minimum to see if it's something I'm doing.

When trying to capture a form input with a file field (hence using new `FormData` instead of `serialize()` ) I'm seeing differences between IE and firefox/chrome/safari.

`add_new` is the id of the form, I've checked it's the only element with that ID on the page, so here's the issue.

In IE this works:

```
$(document).on("submit","#add_new",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

})
```

The form is not submitted, as expected. However, as soon as you add the next line, the script submits to itself.

```
$(document).on("submit","#add_new",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dat = new FormData($('#add_new')[0]);
})
```

This only seems to be happening in IE like I said, no issues elsewhere. I've tried putting return `false` on the end too but no joy.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie

Comment: @Freuh If `preventDefault` doesn't work in IE, why would it work in his first example?

Comment: @Freuh That question is about MooTools. jQuery uses its own event wrapper around native Javascript events, to make it work cross-browser.

Comment: @Barmar, you're right. :)

Comment: `FormData()` is not supported in <IE10 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: Thanks guys, this is in IE11.. @Moob looks right though, IE's developer tools is showing that FormData is undefined. That'd do it then. Will need to find a way to pass a file without using that. I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: There might be something useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899513/send-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax-in-ie

Comment: Brilliant, I'll give that a nose. Cheers. Soon as I'm able (new kid) I'll upvote everything helpful and mark an answer.