# How to send an http multipart POST request with a Blob in it?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, internet-explorer-9, blob, mxhr

I am using multipart XMLHttpRequest to upload files on a Google Drive account, using the syntax described in google's documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#multipart

Here is an simplified example of the request's body.

```
--delim
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

*metadata Json object*

--delim
Content-Type: *datatype*

*data*
--delim--
```

My problem is:

- I'm using JavaScript
- I have to send the data as a Blob
- I can't use Google's JavaScript API
- It must be compatible with Internet Explorer (at least 9).

As you can see, the request consists of 2 strings, with a blob right in between.
But, if I do a concatenation like "a-" + blob + "-b", I of course get the string "a-[object Blob]-b"

So, how can I send a request that contains my blob, and the metadata?

P.S.: I know that I can send the data alone, and then edit the metadata,
but it takes two requests,
one too much...

Comment: Did you try sending a FormData object containing the blob?

Comment: oh, I forgot to say that it needs to work on IE 9, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer,
I had to encode in Base 64 the content of my Blob:

```
var reader = new FileReader
reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
var data = reader.result;
//don't need type informations
data = data.split(",").pop();
```

and just after the "Content-Type" value in the second part of the request,
I added this line:

```
'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'
```

and now it works!

and don't worry, in my code I used my FileReader in an asynchronous way,
I just simplified here for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

The [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object works very well but is not compatible with IE < 10.

For IE versions 9 and below, a different solution is needed. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899513/send-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax-in-ie)'s top answer suggests using [jQuery Form Plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form) as an alternative that is compatible with lower versions of IE.

Upon further inspection, the plugin appears to emulate FormData objects for all non-compliant browsers. The standalone solution for this can be found [here](https://github.com/francois2metz/html5-formdata).